# Lucene PositionIncrementAttribute and search issue

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am new to Lucene.

I have implemented Analyzer and few filters. The original tokenstream is modified and Attributes are inserted as tokens with PositionIncrementAttrbute of 0.

Ex: Sentence: "SO is famous" 
After passing through custom analyzer and few filters and appending Attributes to the tokens, the new Tokenstream we get is 
"SO Noun SocialSite famous JJ Positive" 
I am basically here trying to tag each word. SO is both Noun and SocialSite, famous is Adjective(JJ) and is a Positive word etc.

This is now definitely searchable based on Attributes(Here: Noun, SocialSite, JJ, Positive).i.e., I can search "Noun" or say "Positive" and still get the "SO is famous" as output.

However, since I have put this entire text "SO is famous" as a Field while adding a Document, when I search for say "SocialSite", I get a Document as an output which has "SO is famous" as one of the fields.

However, is it possible to get only "SO" as output rather than an entire text? i.e Only the actual token(the token present in the original input) as output? 
Another example: if I search for say "Positive" I should get "famous" as output and not the entire "SO is famous".

I know that if I put it as a Field in the document, I should be able to get it, but how do I add such a Field? because, only when the Tokens are passed through the filters we get to know what all Attributes would be attached to it, so while we do indexwriter.addDocument() we have no idea about the Attributes.

The typical problem that I see is the indexing is done based on the new tokenstream which is good, but when it retrieves the Document, the document has the older actual Tokenstream(or actual input) and that is what is given as output.

Help/Comments appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use a highlighter?

There are three in Lucene now, but I would start with the newest one, PostingsHighlighter.  I wrote about that one here: http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/12/a-new-lucene-highlighter-is-born.html

The Highlighter identifies which portion of a field's text matches which terms from the query.

Comment: Your blog entry is really interesting. Thanks.
But I still am not sure, how can I use it for my use case above. Could you share any thoughts you have.

Comment: Any help or comment is highly appreciated.